# Sealing classes in C++ and virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-control, virtual-inheritance, sealed

```
class ClassSealer {
private:
   friend class Sealed;
   ClassSealer() {}
};
class Sealed : public ClassSealer
{ 
   // ...
};
class FailsToDerive : public Sealed
{
   // This class is capable of being instantiated
};
```

The above fails to seal the class, but the following works, why?

```
class ClassSealer {
private:
   friend class Sealed;
   ClassSealer() {}
};
class Sealed : public virtual ClassSealer
{ 
   // ...
};
class FailsToDerive : public Sealed
{
   // Cannot be instantiated
};
```

What is happening here? What role does virtual inheritance does play here?

Comment: this technique is obsolete. use the new keyword `final` instead.

Comment: @RichardHodges thanks. But I want to know the reason behind the peculiar behavior mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For normal inheritance, the derived class's constructor only calls the constructors of the *direct* base classes. So in the first example, the constructor of `FailsToDerive` calls the constructor of `Sealed`, which in turn calls the constructor of `ClassSealer`, which it is allowed to do.

The constructor of a *virtually* inherited base, however, is called by the constructor of the *most derived class*. So in the second example, `FailsToDerive`'s constructor needs to be able to call `ClassSealer`'s constructor, which it is not allowed to do since it is not a friend of `ClassSealer`.

Comment: could you please tell where to read about the calling convention of constructors. Thanks!

Comment: Replace "normal" with "non-virtual", unless you want to appear non-virtual-normative?

Comment: @KerrekSB I consider non-virtual to be normal because it's what you get if you don't put any additional keywords.